# How to fix 'An error occurred while installing rake (10.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This is happening in a virtual box running ubuntu 14.04. (Host is ubuntu 18.04) I am trying to get rails 3.2.22.5 running with ruby 2.2.5. So far I've tried installing ruby with rbenv, rvm, and from source, all on seperate virtualbox vm's, all ending with this same error...

I run `bundle install` which gives me this error,

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching rake 10.5.0
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/vagrant/rg/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/cache/rake-10.5.0.gem. It may >be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing rake (10.5.0), and Bundler cannot >continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.5.0' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  auto_tagger was resolved to 0.2.10, which depends on
    capistrano was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
     rake
```

Okay well that should be an easy fix, right?
I run `gem install rake -v '10.5.0' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`

```
Successfully installed rake-10.5.0
Parsing documentation for rake-10.5.0
Done installing documentation for rake after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I can check with `rake --version`

> rake, version 10.5.0

And yes, I cleared the cache file, which results in this:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching rake 10.5.0
Retrying download gem from http://rubygems.org/ due to error (2/4): Errno::ENOLCK No locks available @ rb_file_flock - /home/vagrant/rg/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/cache/rake-10.5.0.gemBundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/vagrant/rg/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/cache/rake-10.5.0.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing rake (10.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.5.0' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Here are the versions of everything

```
Ruby version: 2.2.5
Bundler version: 1.17.3
RubyGems version: 2.4.5.1
Rake version: 10.5.0
```

I would like to note that this is on a new machine. I packaged the vagrant box from my old machine and transferred to the new machine and went to run `bundle exec rails s` and realized rails wasnt installed, even though all my folders and files made it... So I went down this rabbit hole trying to get the environment setup, thus trying rbenv, rvm, and from source, on 3 separate vms.

I've tried everything I could find online over the past 3 days and have spent 15+ hours working to get this running. So needless to say, any help would be incredibly appreciated. I'm starting to wish I never bought this nice shiny new laptop....

Comment: If anybody is running into this same problem using vagrant, here is how I got around it:

Comment out your nfs settings in your Vagrantfile, install everything and get the app running, then you can uncomment your nfs settings.

I'm not sure this is a true fix to the locking problem, but its a way to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end problem was caused by locking, from mounting using nfs.

If you're having this problem while using vagrant check this answer [from another thread.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837962/nfs-error-no-locks-available-after-update-to-16-10)

It fixed the locking errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your last listing goes

```
Retrying download gem from http://rubygems.org/ due to error (2/4): Errno::ENOLCK No locks available
```

which would suggest you are using a filesystem that does not provide locking. You'd need locking to prevent two processes in the system to access the same file simultaneously.

Please try to run this:

```
touch foo
flock foo echo test1 & flock foo test2
rm foo
```

If that succeeded - good for you, we can try to find the issue elsewhere. If that fails, however, your only (probably...) solution would be to get your filesystem a file locking mechanism (it might be related to vagrant, I don't have much experience with that, but there might be a problem with how it is mounted).

Comment: Ahh you are absolutely right. Here is the output from what you suggested,
`[1] 2246
flock: foo: No locks available`

I was able to get everything installed, and the app up and running by commenting my nfs settings, installing everything, and then uncommenting the nfs settings. I guess nfs doesnt have locking?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy to hear I could be of some help! :)